# React Warning: The tag <u1> is unrecognized in this browser

Tags: reactjs, warnings

I'm trying to render a react component as you can see in the next code:

```
render() {
        if (!this.state.loading) {
          return <h1>Loading....</h1>;
        }
        return (
          <div>
              <h2>{ this.state.text }</h2>
            <u1>
              {this.state.users.map((user) => (
                <li key={user.id}>
                  {user.name}
                  <a href={`http://${user.website}`}>Website</a>
                </li>
              ))}
            </u1>
          </div>
        );
      }
```

But I'm getting the warning: `index.js:1 Warning: The tag <u1> is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.`

I don't really understand why I got this warning. Any ideas?

Comment: `ul` (in capital letters UL) is an html element, but `u1` (U1) is not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant `ul` for unordered list instead of `u1`